# Putting a tire wider than the original one

Tags: honda, ford, tires, wheels

I bought a Honda Accord 2007 that comes with 215/50R17 tires. I found that the previous owner changed the back steel rims to Ford rims with tire size (225/50R17).

Thus my question is, can I change the tires that are on the Ford rims to the size 215/50R17? Or this won't work because of the width?

I am asking because I want to have four tires of the same size. Do I need to change the back Ford rims?

Answer (score 1):

The size difference between these two tire sizes is minimal.

[image: Tire Sizes]

You can try it yourself at:

[Tire Size Calculator](https://tiresize.com/calculator/)

There should be no problem going from the 225 width to the 215 width.

Comment: Thanks jwh20! but then why is there 225 on that tire? is it because of the width of the rim?

Comment: @Minions - The original rim would most likely be able to deal with the wider tires. The 225 is the tread width in millimeters, so 10mm wider, or about .393". The 50 is the aspect ratio, which is the size difference between the sidewall and the tread width. In your case,  since it is 50, it is 1/2 (or 50%, same thing) of the tread width. At 225, sidewall height is 112.5mm high. Hope that helps you understand what the numbers mean and the differences between the two.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2! this didn't answer my question. I am asking, why is there 225 width tire rim? is it because of its width? why the previous owner didn't set a 215 instead?

Comment: @Minions - The "225" has ABSOLUTELY nothing to do with the rim. They could have ran the original rim and put the 225 width tires on there without issue (you can probably go +/- 30mm without too much of an issue). If I were a betting man, I'd suggest they found a set of wheels which fit on the car which came with the 225 width tires already on them.

Comment: Tires come in a variety of TREAD WIDTHS.  That's the 215 and 225 that you mentioned in your question.  The width of the rim is not specified in the tire size bue generally a wider tread leads to a wider rim.  But there is a range of tire tread widths that fit on most rims.  In your case the 215 and 225 widths are pretty much interchangeable.  Usually the biggest concern with the wider tire is clearance under the wheel well.