# My ‘07 Honda CRV uses 225/65/R17 tires — can I change to 225/55/R17 tires?

Tags: honda, tires, crv

This is going DOWN in circumference slightly... I know the speedometer will read higher... any other issues?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you're saying the speedo will read higher than what you're actually going, then yes, I'd agree. Why not get a bit wider tires and make up for the difference so you have the same rolling rate (revolutions/mile)? I'd suggest you can change to the smaller tires, but there are so many options out there I bet you'd find what you need and not worry about the speedo.

Comment: Duplicate, just see the answer here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/85902/10976

Comment: Note that that linked question also has a link to a tire tool that will help you determine whether a particular size is a good fit, replacing your OEMs.

Comment: I saw a great deal on lightly used 225/55/R17 snows, but chose to NOT replace my aged 225/65/R17 tires with them because their lower diameter = higher wheel rpm and related problems of: speedo reading too low / more wear & tear on drive train components / lower vehicle ride height of nearly 1” (undesirable in deep snow). I was told that varying by more than “5” on either of the first two numbers of the tire size exceeds “the 3% rule” and may negatively affect handling, as well as the above stated issues.  Go from a 65% aspect ratio to 60, but 55 is too low. (This is NOT a WIDTH issue.)